# How to create window with full screen width/height in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I'm trying to create a window with full screen size, but not both coordinates, only width or height. Some windows in Windows span full height or full width, my window should appear this way.

I tried doing resizable fullscreen mode, but it not what I am looking for. Is there any flag or method to do this?

edit: i tried using geometry me/thod, state method and attrinbutes method

```py
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

It didnt help, cause it doesn't allow you to see Windows toolbar and makes window fullsize by both coordinates, I only need 1 - width ot height

```py
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height/2))
```

its not so clean, window is a bit unaligned.

```py
window_name.state('zoomed')
```

it seems helpful, but `state` maximizes in both directions, and I don't know if I could easily do the same with 1 direction

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and tell us why these attempts are not sufficient for you. At this point it is very hard to even make a guess what you might want to achieve. Please add enough code and details to your question, so others can possibly answer it.

Comment: Yeah, following [Tkinter Full Screen](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-full-screen-window-in-tkinter/), there are 3 different ways to do it, have you check these?

Comment: You can combine `window_name.maxsize()` and `window_name.state('zoomed')` to maximize in one direction only.

Comment: It helped! I was getting window size instead of screen size

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full screen window, use:

```
win = Tk()
win.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

If you just want it to be full screen in one direction, you can first get the height/width of the screen and then set the window size:

```
win = Tk()

screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()

# replace either screen_width and screen_height to change the appropriate dimension
win.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried but there is a small gap, it's unaligned. I'll try to align it with geometry('widthxheight+x+y'), set x to some small negative value